# How to save map markers in sql lite database with notes?

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, android-maps-v2

I have so far figured out how to get a marker on the screen by tapping, and it shows the longitude and latitude numbers, I wish to be able to save markers in a the SQL lite database with a note on the marker, so when the map is loaded and the markers loaded with the map, when a user taps the marker information will show above the marker. Here is my map class so far:

```
public class Map extends  FragmentActivity {






GoogleMap googleMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();

    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)
    getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    // Getting a reference to the map
    googleMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();


    googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {

            // Creating a marker
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

            // Setting the position for the marker
            markerOptions.position(latLng);

            // Setting the title for the marker.
            // This will be displayed on taping the marker
            markerOptions.title(latLng.latitude + " : " + latLng.longitude);

            // Clears the previously touched position
            googleMap.clear();

            // Animating to the touched position
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

            // Placing a marker on the touched position
            googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        }
    });
}


  @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }



  private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (googleMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (googleMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }


  private void setUpMap() {

      googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
      googleMap.getMyLocation();
    }


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set on map click listener (or on LongClick listener) like this:

```
map.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {

        }
    });
```

In that listener you will get LatLng point of clicked position on map. Then you will just create marker like this:

```
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(point)
        .title("title")
        .snippet("snippet")
        .icon(icon));
```

For saving the markers just use List or HashMap, because map has no such method for getting added markers (maybe I am wrong).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you I will try your code and see if I can get it to work!!

Comment: Your answer was a tiny part of what I eventually came up with, but it provided a good start, take the bounty.